# Quarkus and Keycloak: evaluate scope based permission

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus

I have a REST API, that should use Keycloak for authorizing incoming requests. I have problems with configuring desired scopes in my API.
In Keycloak I defined a client for my API, a client for the calling service and two users. Both users have some realm roles. The client for my API defines a resource, some scopes (eg read, delete), policies and permissions.
One permissions allows an user with the admin role to perform scopes read and delete on the resource. The other allows an user with the monitoring role to read the resource.
I understand that the path of my endpoint will be checked against the path defined in the Keycloak client resource.

My concrete problem here is that I don't know how to tell my endpoint, which scopes he needs.

In the end I want to have multiple endpoints with the same path but different scopes (for each HTTP method).

Here is my example config:

```
quarkus.http.port=8080
quarkus.resteasy.path=/api
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://myUrl:8443/auth/realms/enaq
quarkus.oidc.client-id=rest-api
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=secret-string
quarkus.oidc.enabled=true
quarkus.application.name=keycloak-test-api
quarkus.application.version=0.0.1
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
```

Here is an example implementation:

```
@Path("/measurements")
public class MeasurementResource {

    @Autowired
    MeasurementService delegate;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}/{from}/{to}/{resolution}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MeasurementHistory getMeasurementHistory(@PathParam("id") String deviceId, @PathParam("from") Long from,
            @PathParam("to") Long to, @PathParam("resolution") Integer resolution) {
        return delegate.getMeasurementHistory(from, to, resolution, deviceId);
    }
}
```

In my example my permissions will be evaluated, but only the admin gets access. The monitoring user will be denied, although he should be able to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to define the exact scopes that should be protected and map them to the appropriate HTTP verb, you should configure the policy enforcer as documented [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_filter).

There is no documentation on Quarkus side yet that shows how to map that to properties (`application.properties`) but it should be quite trivial to do so. You can grab an example from [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/integration-tests/keycloak-authorization/src/main/resources/application.properties).

Another option is to set the `quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.http-method-as-scope=true`. By doing that, your resources would be associated with scopes such as `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc. And the policy enforcer will enforce access accordingly without forcing you to map paths in your configuration file.

Comment: Did you try adding @RolesAllowed("your-role") to your endpoint ?

Comment: @iabughosh I defined policies and permissions in keycloak. Keycloak should check whether a role is allowed to access a resource. Therefore I wouldn't use the annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your approaches Pedro. I like the second one the most, but I actually have trouble with that one. I can't figure out what property is necessary to set the scope. Btw the link was really helpful for other configs, too.

Comment: nvm. I think I found the right property. I was kinda blind :D  But the corresponding property in the json file from the first link is an array. Do know how I would set the values in the property file? Like _quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.2.methods.1.scopes=create_  or _quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.2.methods.1.scopes=create, read_ or _quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.2.methods.1.scopes.1=create_