# Quarkus with Keycloak scopes and permissions

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

We are running into something rather strange when using permissions and scopes from Keycloak with Quarkus.
What we want to accomplish: setup an HTTP API authenticated and authorized using Keycloak with scopes and resources (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_permission_create_scope).
We have following `application.properties` file:

```
quarkus.log.level=DEBUG

quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=<keycloak-url>
quarkus.oidc.client-id=<client-id>
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=<secret>
quarkus.http.cors=true

quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.lazy-load-paths=true
```

Important in this properties-file to us is the enabling of the policy-enforcer but that's normal configuration in this case, just pointing it out.
We have a resource name `Test` and scope names `read` and `update`. We are not able to get the correct permissions from keycloak if the URI is not filled in for the resource. From the moment we matched this with the quarkus URI, we were able to fetch this permission block but only that one, using following snippet:

```
public CompletionStage<Tenant> getByName(@PathParam String name) {
        return identity.checkPermission(new KeycloakPermission("resource-guid", "read")).thenApply(
                authorized -> {
                    if (!authorized){
                        throw new ForbiddenException("Not allowed to read");
                    }
                    return new Test(name);
                }
        );
    }
```

The `KeycloakPermission` looks like this:

```
public class KeycloakPermission extends BasicPermission {
    private final String actions;

    public KeycloakPermission(final String name, final String actions) {
        super(name, actions);
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    @Override
    public String getActions() {
        return actions;
    }
}
```

Because otherwise I couldn't find any implementation which also returns the actions to the authorization context.
I have following questions:

- Is it possible to check this resource-scope combination

  - without configuring the path in keycloak
  - by configuring this in `application.properties`-file?
- If we use `resource-name` instead of `resource-guid`, the variable `authorized` in our method is always true because of this line of code: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/ab2d1546b4495b588e45f42dd41f2cebd2d3f796/core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/AuthorizationContext.java#L72. This is fixed by using the id of the resource and not the name. Are we missing something here? We only want the user to be authorized when he has the scope on a specific resource but the PathConfig `current` is autofilled when adding filling out the URI in the keycloak resource.
- Have we missed something concerning the custom created permission? I would expect this to be available somewhere?

PS: if somebody is able to add the tag quarkus-keycloak, would be nice.

Comment: Can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393229/quarkus-and-keycloak-evaluate-scope-based-permission help ?